# Is it possible to copy QCombobox to another QCombobox

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-designer, qcombobox

I use Qt Designer to build my UI layout. On the layout, I have a combobox named `cb_fac_cd`. In my code I have a function that will automatically build a combobox based on the list I'm attempting to build. I have a lot of these lists defined in the database and this function spits out a QComboBox.

Unfortunately, until now I've only used this function to add cellWidgets to QTableWidgets. It works perfectly there. Now I want to populate this preexisting combobox.

It seems that a simple
`self.ui.cb_fac_cd = makeComboBox('FACILITIES')` doesn't work. I can see that the function returns the QComboBox as usual, but the cb_fac_cd combobox remains unpopulated.

How can I copy or assign the returned combobox to the one build in Qt Designer?

I am using PyQt, but that shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: more code would be helpful to find the issue. Where are you passing the combobox to this function? Where is the combobox being populated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot replace objects which are part of the .h files generated by Qt's UIC mechanism (though I cannot confirm that 100% right now).

What I usually do in such cases is to have an empty layout in the ui file and then do the following:
(Note that I'm using Qt/C++ syntax as I don't know the pyqt syntax but I think you will get the idea)

```
QComboBox* pNewComboBox = makeComboBox( "FACILITIES" );
ui.pComboBoxLayout->addWidget( pComboBox );
```

Additionally, if possible for your program, consider using an enumeration rather than a string for your makeComboBox function. This is usually faster and safer.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should either

1. Change makeComboBox to populateComboBox(QComboBox *p) and pass it the combobox in your layout to fill, or
2. Create and add the QComboBox to your layout dynamically and remove it from your .ui

Answer (score 1):

You can change the model from you Ui to the one you get from the other combobox:

```
tempCombo = makeComboBox( "FACILITIES" )
self.ui.cb_fac_cd.setModel(tempCombo.model())
```

---

But for that part:

> I have a lot of these lists defined in the database and this function
>   spits out a QComboBox. Unfortunately, until now I've only used this function to add
>   cellWidgets to QTableWidgets.

If the data comes from a database, you might want to look at [QSqlRelationalTableModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqlrelationaltablemodel.html) to avoid doing that manually.